# I accidentally deleted var directory in my linux opensuse system. I can't acces the GUI as var/lib/gdm also got deleted

Tags: directory, deleted-files, var

Message shown:
Server authorization directory (daemon/ServeAuthDir) is set to /var/lib/gdm but this doesn't exist.

Comment: How far can you get in the boot/login sequence?

Comment: As the PC starts it shows the message which i have wriiten above. And then it remains in the command terminal mode. I am able to login to root.. but it shows the message that some" level 5 files" missing.

Comment: Time to restore from backup.

Answer (score 1):

You could recreate that directory but that would not help much.

The best solution would be to reinstall all packages which create diriectories and files in /var.

The best way to do that is probably to check all installed packages for files in `/var`:

```
rpm -qa | while read package; do
    if rpm -ql "$package" | grep -q /var; then
        zypper install --force "$package"
    fi
done
```

You should create `/var/tmp` and `/var/log` with these permissions before:

```
drwxrwxrwt 1 root root 425K  2. Mai 00:53 /var/tmp/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  946  1. Mai 23:53 /var/log/
```

Other directories may be necessary.

Maybe it is necessary to install the packages in the right order. This should be possible by using a single install command with all the package names as arguments so that `zypper` uses the dependencies for the right order. I do not know, though, whether dependencies are considered at all during a reinstall.